# external jQuery scroll not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, scrolltop

I am trying to make a sticky top navigation bar that follows the screen when it reaches the top of the page. Basically, when it reaches the top of the page, the position is changed from relative to fixed.

My code works when I include the jScript internally inside the body of the HTML code. I am new to using jQuery, so if you guys can help me out.

Here is my html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="main-style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="sticky_nav.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
        <header class="banner">
            <div class="logo"></div>
            <div class ="contact-info">
                <div class="fb"></div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <nav class="top-nav" id="top-nav">
        </nav>
        <div class="main">
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my css:

```
body {
    padding-top: 450px;
    background-image: url(background.jpg);
}

.banner {
    left: 50%;
    margin: 0 0 0 -25%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    height: 475px;
    width: 950px;
    z-index: -10;
    background-image: url(img4.jpg);
}

.top-nav {
    position: relative;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background: #F0742F;
    width: 950px;
    height: 70px;
    z-index: 20;
    margin-bottom: -60px;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.top-nav a {
    font: 25px bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFF;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

.top-nav-scrolled {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    margin: 0 0 0 -25%;
}
```

Here is my js:

```
var tn = $(".top-nav");
var tns = $(".top-nav-scrolled");
var hdr = $('header').height();

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function() {
    if( $(this).scrollTop() > (hdr - 20) ) {
            if( $(this).scrollTop() > (hdr - 20) ) {
        tn.add(tns);
    } 
    else {
        tn.remove(tns);
    })
});
```

When I put the js code internally, between script tags it works. So I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: As you defined, the `sticky_nav.js` must be in same folder as html file is (Check F12->Network to see if script was loaded). By the way, you should not change all the styles via script, just add/remove the class and define class in CSS. In your case you could go with: `tn.toggleClass('fixed_element', $(this).scrollTop() > (hdr - 20))`;

Comment: Aff I see now, put your `tn`, `tns` and `hdr` variable definitions inside document-ready function (these elements do not exist in time the script executes).

Comment: By moving the variables inside the function, didn't change anything unfortunately

Comment: But you changed the script and added errors inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you call your `sticky_nav.js` in document `head`, non of the body elements do not exist yet. So, the error is in `tn`, `tns` and `hdr` declarations: they should be inside dom-ready function.

In addition, best praxis would be change the class via script, define class styles via CSS:

```
$(document).on('ready', function(){
    var tn = $(".top-nav");
    var hdr = $('header').height();
    $(window).on('scroll', function() {
        tn.toggleClass('top-nav-scrolled', $(this).scrollTop() > (hdr - 20))
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much! That works great. Just need to resize it in my css code.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).scrollTop() > (hdr - 20)
```

looks weird.

I believe you need to cache the offset().top of the nav-bar (because it will change dynamically with position changes) and then check for it reached by window.

```
var tn = $(".top-nav");
var tns = $(".top-nav-scrolled");
var hdr = $('header').height();
var offset = tn.offset().top;

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if( $(this).scrollTop() > offset) {
            tn.css("position", "fixed");
            tn.css("top", "0");
            tn.css("left", "50%");
            tn.css("margin","0 0 0 -25%");
        }
        else {
            tn.css("position", "relative");
            tn.removeAttr("left");
            tn.removeAttr("top");
            tn.removeAttr("margin");
        }
    })
});
```

Like that.

And also, you can pass plain object to css() method, like this:

```
tn.css({
    "position": "fixed",
    "top": "0"
});
```

and so on.